# i can't print the linkedlist elements in reverse order using recursion

Tags: java, linked-list

I am a beginner in java .I am implementing recursion in linked lists to print the elements in reverse order but i think that there is a semantic error in my code , check my code(especially that reverse method) thanks in an advance.
 output:78 30 52 send after which item count from head u need to insert
package practice;

```
public class Linkedlist {

    Node head;

    public Linkedlist() {
        head = null;
    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        Node obj1 = new Node(data);
        obj1.next = head;
        head = obj1;
    }

    public void append(int data) {
        Node newn = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            newn.next = null;
            head = newn;
            return;
        }
        Node n = head;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        newn.next = null;
        n.next = newn;

    }

    void delete(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            return;
        } else if (head.data == data) {
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr.next != null) {
            if (curr.next.data == data) {
                curr.next = curr.next.next;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }

    void insertAt(int count, int data) {
        Node h = head;
        if (count == 0) {
            this.insert(data);
            return;
        }
        while (h.next != null) {
            if (count == 0) {
                Node f = new Node(data);
                f = h.next;
                h = f;
                return;
            }
            count--;
            h = h.next;
        }
    }

    public void reverse() {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("null");
        } else {
            this.reverseRecursive(head);
        }
    }

    private void reverseRecursive(Node nod) {
        if (nod == null) {
            return;
        }
        reverseRecursive(nod.next);
        System.out.print(nod.data + " ");
    }

    class Node {
        Node next;
        int data;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Linkedlist obj = new Linkedlist();
        obj.insert(78);
        obj.insert(30);
        obj.insert(52);
        obj.reverse();
        System.out.println("send after which item count from head u need to insert");
        obj.insertAt(2, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not answering your Question but please, PLEASE read basic code formatting rules.
I can't read it.
For example: Write all Classes begining with a capital letter and all methods begining with a small letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code, I don't think there is anything wrong with your Reverse method. It is actually printing in reverse order. What's throwing you off is probably the way you are inserting the elements. Your insert() method is actually a stack. ( It inserts at top ). So after all insertions, head points to 52 and not 78. So when you print, the reverse list is printed as :

```
78 30 52
```

Also, your code needs a bit of formatting and should follow java conventions. Method names start with lower case and class names with uppercase. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

In your LinkedList instead of using the insert method, which add an element at the head use the method append which adds the element at the end of the LinkedList and then call the reverse method.